# How to get a variable from java method to a jsp page

Tags: java

```
String strQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM public.acsis_lab_test_results where reviewed = true";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(strQuery);

            String Countrow="";
              while(rs.next()){
              Countrow = rs.getString(1);
              System.out.println("Total test reviewed :" +Countrow);
              request.setAttribute("Countrow", Countrow);
               }
```

jsp page

```
   <% 
    
        String val = request.getParameter("Countrow");
        out.println("Total test reviewed :" + val);
      
    %>
```

countrow is coming back as null
help please

Comment: That code should probably return the value you're interested in and your jsp code should call that method. But without more context that's just an educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.getAttribute(..)` as below

```
   <% 
    
        String val = request.getAttribute("Countrow");
        out.println("Total test reviewed :" + val);
      
    %>
```

Comment: its not working